# SQL Developer SQL Tuning Advisor not all variables bound

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-tuning

I'm trying to use the SQL tuning advisor with SQL Developer (versions 4.1.3.20 and 17.2.0.188).  Queries using more than one instance of a bind variable, for example:

```
select * from dual where :one = :one;
```

are causing an error in the SQL Tuning Advisor:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERRORS SECTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- ORA-01008: not all variables bound

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a workaround or some other method to get the same SQL tuning info for queries that have multiple instances of one or more bind variables?

Comment: Even though you're naming then you can't reuse binds and they're always positionally based. You need to bind it twice, in order.

Comment: @Ben isn't that SQL Developer's problem?  I'm not writing SQL developer here, I'm using it.

Comment: I think you've found a bug, if i have 2 binds of different names, the advisor runs w/o a problem

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the Tuning Advisor binds by position (not by name). So the workaround would be to rename all the repeated variable instances. Adding a numbered suffix would be enough. In your example, you would have to name your variables :one and :one_1.

```
select * from dual where :one = :one_1;
```

I know, it's not ideal, but it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you want to use ":one = :one", you can replace it as "1 = 1", or add one more variable assigned by the same value, select * from dual where :one = :two;